# ¿Como contar una palabra repetida de una frase?

Tags: javascript

Quiero contar cuantas veces se repite una palabra dada dentro de una frase y retornarla en número, osea las veces que se repite esa palabra en específico.

Ambos datos son parámetros que me dan como argumento, lo que significa que tengo que ser dinámica con mi código, por ejemplo:

si mi función recibe como primer parametro: "Esa tortuga, es la tortuga mas rapida" y como segundo: "tortuga" debería obtener 2(ya que esta es la cantidad de veces que se repite dicha palabra en la frase dada)

Como tal ya tengo mi codigo, sin embargo tengo la intuición de que solo me retorna las veces que se repite un carácter y no una palabra, por lo que al final me da 0 en todos los escenarios:

```
let i = 0;
let repeatWord = 0

while(i < phrase.length){
 if (phrase[i] == word) {

    repeatWord = repeatWord + 1
    
}
i = i+1
 } 

   return repeatWord
```

Tengo la idea por el momento que puedo utilizar un split y un join, pero no se como aplicarlo...

Comment: Déjame entender... tu función recibe 2 parámetros, una es la frase y la otra es la palabra que contará cuantas se repiten en la frase... no?

Comment: Una es la frase dada y la otra es la palabra la cual queremos ver si se repite dentro de la frase, si

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías utilizar dos **`for`** para evaluar si encuentran palabras repetidas en tu frase. Las palabras repetidas que serán evaluadas son del segundo parámetro que recibe tu función, es decir, si tu segundo parámetro es **`tortuga`**, buscará cuantas **`tortuga`** se repite en tu frase. De esta forma vemos que si encuentra repetidos en la frase se irá acumulando y así sucesivamente, veamos:

```js
function contarPalabras(frase,palabra) {
  fraseArr = frase.replace(",","").split(" "); //quitamos las comas de la frase y usamos a los espacios como separador, devolviendo un array => ["Esa", "tortuga", "es", "la", "mas"...]
  obj = []; // inicializamos a "obj" en donde se acumularán los repetidos
  for (i = 0; i < fraseArr.length; i++) { //recorremos el array que nos trae el split()
    obj[fraseArr[i]] = 1;
    for (j = 0; j < fraseArr.length; j++) { //volvemos a recorrer el array
      if (i !== j) {
        if (fraseArr[i] === fraseArr[j]) { //si encuentra elementos repetidos...
          obj[fraseArr[i]]++; // acumulamos los repetidos
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return (obj[palabra]); //retornamos la cantidad de repetidos de "palabra", osea de tortuga
}
console.log(contarPalabras('Esa tortuga es la mas rapida', 'tortuga')); //hay 1 "tortuga"
console.log(contarPalabras('Esa tortuga, es la tortuga mas rapida', 'tortuga')); //hay 2 "tortuga"
console.log(contarPalabras('Esa tortuga, es la tortuga mas rapida, la mejor tortuga', 'tortuga')); //hay 3 "tortuga"
```

Comment: Precisamente lo resolví ayer jasjdaj, sin embargo, tu solución es muy interesante. Yo intente sacar cada palabra por medio del separador atreves de cada espacio (" ") y devolviendo un nuevo array con un .join, a partir de ahi, recorrer el arreglo y utilizar un condicional, es casi igual solo que utilicé el metodo .join para almacenarlos. Gracias por tu ayuda <3

Comment: Me alegro que lo haya solucionado. ¡Saludos!.